# Can´t save paypal ipn values into a database

Tags: php, mysql, paypal-ipn

I have implemented a paypal ipn process. I want to retrieve some data from the ipn and save it in a database table. The problem is it doesn´t work. I used the part of the procedure from a tutorial **http://tutorialzine.com/2010/05/donation-center-php-mysql-paypal-api/**

Nelow is the code I have used.
**ipn.php**

```
<?php

require "paypal_integration_class/paypal.class.php";
require "config.php";
require "connect.php";

$p = new paypal_class;
$p->paypal_url = $payPalURL;

if ($p->validate_ipn()) {
    if($p->ipn_data['payment_status']=='Completed')
    {
        $amount = $p->ipn_data['mc_gross'] - $p->ipn_data['mc_fee'];

        mysql_query("   INSERT INTO dc_donations (transaction_id,donor_email,amount,original_request)
                        VALUES (
                            '".esc($p->ipn_data['txn_id'])."',
                            '".esc($p->ipn_data['payer_email'])."',
                            ".(float)$amount.",
                            '".esc(http_build_query($_POST))."'
                        )");
    }
}

function esc($str)
{
    global $link;
    return mysql_real_escape_string($str,$link);
}
?>
```

**connect.php**

```
/* Database config */

$db_host        = "localhost";
$db_user        = "egesachi_ipn";
$db_pass        = "lollipop";
$db_database        = "egesachi_ipn";

/* End config */


$link = @mysql_connect($db_host,$db_user,$db_pass) or die('Unable to establish a DB connection');

mysql_set_charset('utf8');
mysql_select_db($db_database,$link);

?>
```

**config.php**

```
<?php

// Fill your PayPal email below.
// This is where you will receive the donations.

$myPayPalEmail = 'ben@center.org';


// The paypal URL:
$payPalURL = 'https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr';


// Your goal in USD:
$goal = 100;


// Demo mode is set - set it to false to enable donations.
// When enabled PayPal is bypassed.

$demoMode = false;

if($demoMode)
{
    $payPalURL = 'demo_mode.php';
}
?>
```

**paypal_integration_class/paypal.class.php**
Below is the URL where the script above is from.
**http://www.phpclasses.org/package/2249-PHP-Process-Paypal-payment-interactions.html**

```
class paypal_class {

   var $last_error;                 // holds the last error encountered

   var $ipn_log;                    // bool: log IPN results to text file?
   var $ipn_log_file;               // filename of the IPN log
   var $ipn_response;               // holds the IPN response from paypal   
   var $ipn_data = array();         // array contains the POST values for IPN

   var $fields = array();           // array holds the fields to submit to paypal


   function paypal_class() {

      // initialization constructor.  Called when class is created.

      $this->paypal_url = 'https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr';

      $this->last_error = '';

      $this->ipn_log_file = 'ipn_log.txt';
      $this->ipn_log = true;
      $this->ipn_response = '';

      // populate $fields array with a few default values.  See the paypal
      // documentation for a list of fields and their data types. These defaul
      // values can be overwritten by the calling script.

      $this->add_field('rm','2');           // Return method = POST
      $this->add_field('cmd','_xclick'); 

   }

   function add_field($field, $value) {

      // adds a key=>value pair to the fields array, which is what will be 
      // sent to paypal as POST variables.  If the value is already in the 
      // array, it will be overwritten.

      $this->fields["$field"] = $value;
   }

   function submit_paypal_post() {

      // this function actually generates an entire HTML page consisting of
      // a form with hidden elements which is submitted to paypal via the 
      // BODY element's onLoad attribute.  We do this so that you can validate
      // any POST vars from you custom form before submitting to paypal.  So 
      // basically, you'll have your own form which is submitted to your script
      // to validate the data, which in turn calls this function to create
      // another hidden form and submit to paypal.

      // The user will briefly see a message on the screen that reads:
      // "Please wait, your order is being processed..." and then immediately
      // is redirected to paypal.

      echo "<html>\n";
      echo "<head><title>Processing Payment...</title></head>\n";
      echo "<body onLoad=\"document.form.submit();\">\n";
      echo "<center><h3>Please wait, your order is being processed...</h3></center>\n";
      echo "<form method=\"post\" name=\"form\" action=\"".$this->paypal_url."\">\n";

      foreach ($this->fields as $name => $value) {
         echo "<input type=\"hidden\" name=\"$name\" value=\"$value\">";
      }

      echo "</form>\n";
      echo "</body></html>\n";

   }

   function validate_ipn() {

      // parse the paypal URL
      $url_parsed=parse_url($this->paypal_url);        

      // generate the post string from the _POST vars aswell as load the
      // _POST vars into an arry so we can play with them from the calling
      // script.
      $post_string = '';    
      foreach ($_POST as $field=>$value) { 
         $this->ipn_data["$field"] = $value;
         $post_string .= $field.'='.urlencode($value).'&'; 
      }
      $post_string.="cmd=_notify-validate"; // append ipn command

      // open the connection to paypal
      $fp = fsockopen($url_parsed[host],"80",$err_num,$err_str,30); 
      if(!$fp) {

         // could not open the connection.  If loggin is on, the error message
         // will be in the log.
         $this->last_error = "fsockopen error no. $errnum: $errstr";
         $this->log_ipn_results(false);       
         return false;

      } else { 

         // Post the data back to paypal
         fputs($fp, "POST $url_parsed[path] HTTP/1.1\r\n"); 
         fputs($fp, "Host: $url_parsed[host]\r\n"); 
         fputs($fp, "Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\n"); 
         fputs($fp, "Content-length: ".strlen($post_string)."\r\n"); 
         fputs($fp, "Connection: close\r\n\r\n"); 
         fputs($fp, $post_string . "\r\n\r\n"); 

         // loop through the response from the server and append to variable
         while(!feof($fp)) { 
            $this->ipn_response .= fgets($fp, 1024); 
         } 

         fclose($fp); // close connection

      }

      if (eregi("VERIFIED",$this->ipn_response)) {

         // Valid IPN transaction.
         $this->log_ipn_results(true);
         return true;       

      } else {

         // Invalid IPN transaction.  Check the log for details.
         $this->last_error = 'IPN Validation Failed.';
         $this->log_ipn_results(false);   
         return false;

      }

   }

   function log_ipn_results($success) {

      if (!$this->ipn_log) return;  // is logging turned off?

      // Timestamp
      $text = '['.date('m/d/Y g:i A').'] - '; 

      // Success or failure being logged?
      if ($success) $text .= "SUCCESS!\n";
      else $text .= 'FAIL: '.$this->last_error."\n";

      // Log the POST variables
      $text .= "IPN POST Vars from Paypal:\n";
      foreach ($this->ipn_data as $key=>$value) {
         $text .= "$key=$value, ";
      }

      // Log the response from the paypal server
      $text .= "\nIPN Response from Paypal Server:\n ".$this->ipn_response;

      // Write to log
      $fp=fopen($this->ipn_log_file,'a');
      fwrite($fp, $text . "\n\n"); 

      fclose($fp);  // close file
   }

   function dump_fields() {

      // Used for debugging, this function will output all the field/value pairs
      // that are currently defined in the instance of the class using the
      // add_field() function.

      echo "<h3>paypal_class->dump_fields() Output:</h3>";
      echo "<table width=\"95%\" border=\"1\" cellpadding=\"2\" cellspacing=\"0\">
            <tr>
               <td bgcolor=\"black\"><b><font color=\"white\">Field Name</font></b></td>
               <td bgcolor=\"black\"><b><font color=\"white\">Value</font></b></td>
            </tr>"; 

      ksort($this->fields);
      foreach ($this->fields as $key => $value) {
         echo "<tr><td>$key</td><td>".urldecode($value)."&nbsp;</td></tr>";
      }

      echo "</table><br>"; 
   }
}
```

**paypal html checkout form**

```
<form action="https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post">

    <!-- Identify your business so that you can collect the payments. -->
    <input type="hidden" name="business"
        value="ben@egesachildrencenter.org">

    <!-- Specify a Donate button. -->
    <input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_donations">

    <!-- Specify details about the contribution -->
    <input type="hidden" name="item_name" value="<?php echo $sponsored; ?>">
    <input type="hidden" name="item_number" value="<?php echo $pupilid; ?>">
    <input type="hidden" name="amount" value="25.00">
    <input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="USD">
    <input type="hidden" name="return" value="http://www.center.org/pap/needy.php">
    <input type="hidden" name="notify_url" value="http://www.center.org/pap/ipn.php"> 
    <!-- Display the payment button. -->
    <input type="image" name="submit" border="0"
    src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/i/btn/btn_donate_LG.gif"
    alt="PayPal - The safer, easier way to pay online">
    <img alt="" border="0" width="1" height="1"
    src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/i/scr/pixel.gif" >
</form>
```

Please help me to find where I am going wrong or suggest another way of achieving th same result. Thanks.

Comment: Where are you checking this? On your localhost?

Comment: Paypal can't see your localhost so you are not getting an IPN from PayPal.

Comment: sorry.about the localhost that is just the server name.its not a localhost.sorry for misunderstanding your question.

Comment: sorry again i seem not understand.the localhost am using is in cpanel how do connect to the server in cpanel.

Comment: Is the server on your local computer? Are you running XAMPP or WAMP or some sort? Is your localhost ip address 127.0.0.1?